# Изображения из галереи в BottomSheetDialog (как в Viber)

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь найти библиотеку в которой реализовано было :
изображения из галереи в bottom bar. Может кто сталкивался?
Такая функция реализована в viber, по нажатию на икнопку нижний бар приподнимается и предполагаю,что через рекасл вью отображаются фото из галереи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Viber ни разу не видел. На скрине мало инфы. Не видно когда и как появляется. Но скорее всего это BottomSheetDialog

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
а как тогда впихнуть рекасл вью..

Comment: сделать кастомную разметку и впихнуть

Comment: @tim_taller
может примеры есть?

Comment: что там на полу? мясо какое-то) 
Это не диалог точно - даже не пытайтесь смотреть в сторону BottomSheet и любых других диалогоподобных испусканий. В целом это кастомный элемент со своей логикой, и списком внутри.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, через BottomSheetDialogFragment такое сделать вообще не проблема. Туда и разметку обычную можно поместить...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб =) не проблема накрутить, окей. А в каком состоянии будет находится чат при открытом диалоге тогда? Думаю дальше не стоит вести мысль.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, ОК, тогда можно просто BottomSheet, не диалог. Тогда не будет паузы в чате)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 
так какой варинт все еж выбрать?))

Comment: Не могу дать ответ. Вы так и не рассказали что конкретно вам нужно

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
если вы так тонко троллите,то зря)я в шапке темы все указал

Comment: Обычный `BottomSheet`. Не понимаю в чем проблема поместить `view` в него.. Панель для набора сообщения скорее всего выступает пикером `peek_height`. А далее тупо открывается сам `bottomsheet` с сеткой фотографий

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ здесь - [Flipboard/bottomsheet](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)

Comment: Не пойму, что вам надо. Это тот же `bottomsheet` только с анимацией открытия/закрытия. Это сделать можно и в виджете из библиотеки поддержки.

Comment: И что-то мне подсказывает что он скоро будет `deprecated`, все-таки из либы суппорта виджет лучше (ну, будет лучше точно)